# java : Make it the best "Searching method"

Tags: java, swing

I have design the search method. According to my requirement, If a user wants to search a customer’s record, he/she can input the customer’s family name or given name into the name text field and then click the search button. The following two screen shots show  an example of  the events before and after button click (with input the name to be searched is Lee)

[image]

[image]

And below is the code for searching. It is working fine but I want to make it better?

```
 private void search()
        {
            String studentName=CNameTextField.getText();
            String record="";
            int count=0;

            for(int i=0; i<myList.size();i++)
              {
                String name=myList.get(i).getName();

                 String [] splitName= name.split(" ");

                 if(studentName.equals(splitName[0]) || studentName.equals(splitName[1]))
                    {
                        count++;
                        record=record+"\n"+myList.get(i).toString();

                    }
                display.setText("");
                display.append(count + " result(s) found for "+ studentName);
                display.append("\n "+ record);
              }


    }
```

Comment: do you mean faster? better scaling?

Comment: Might want to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, though how large will the dataset you're working with be? If it's just a couple hundred entries in the list, straight linear search would be fine (and frankly, could be fine for even more). If you have more, the question might be about what data structures you're using to represent all these objects. Profile profile profile if you're afraid of performance or memory concerns.

Comment: i want it in better logic if possible. and that's only for 4 records.

Comment: The logic you have works, though I would ask what the expectation is, as there's a lot going on beyond just logic. You type in `"Lee"`, is that just looking for first/last names that have `"Lee"`? Or do you want everything that contains the substring "Lee" to match? Is that what people who use this program would expect? If it was just "all names with 'lee'", then perhaps you could use `studentName.indexOf(name) >= 0` (and possibly do case-insensitive match as well). I also don't know how you represent your data (you just tell us that it's in `myList`, maybe you can have more object fields

Comment: If you use a database for your data, you can delegate the search operation to the database. As a user I would also want the LIKE behavior which is available on e.g. a MySQL database, case (in)sensitive searching, ...

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you've basically got a list of `String` items, and you're searching through all of them for the value?

My recommendation would be to create Objects for each line in your DisplayArea, rather than `String`s. For example, when you read in the input file for your DisplayArea, do the `split()` for each line and create objects of type `Customer` that have fields called `ID`, `name`, `room`, etc. This would be better OO programming anyway - `String`s don't really have any meaning, whereas a `Customer` has meaning.

If you do this, in the search you can simply loop over all the `Customer`s in the list, asking whether the `name.equals(customer.getName());` This would remove the need to split the line every time you search.